# Saving an array of strings to an SQL column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, session, visual-studio-2012

I want to create a "sessions" table in an SQL database for a school project. Each session should have:

- Session ID
- Lecturer name
- Time and date
- Module name
- Course name
- List of student IDs
- List of student statuses(Present, absent, late)

How can I represent such a thing ???

Is it better to create ONE table to represent all sessions, where each session would be one row, and have an array of strings in each column that represents the names, IDs, and status of students??

OR

Create a new table for each new session ??

What is better, and please explain how to do it briefly.

Bear in mind, that I would need to insert/delete/update/view each table from a C# windows application, and the maximum expected number of sessions is just 100.

Also, I am using SQL Server 2012 with a C# windows application developed with Visual Studio 2012

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should have 3 tables :

**Students**

```
------------------------------------
| StudentID | FirstName | LastName |
|-----------|-----------|----------|
|   4456    |   John    |   Doe    |
|   6678    |   Billy   |   Bob    |
------------------------------------
```

Here StudentID is Primary Key

**Sessions**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| SessionID | Lecturer | DateTime |     Module       |    Course    |
|-----------|----------|----------|------------------|--------------|
|    1      |  Mr.Joe  | 524523461| Natural Sciences | Oceanography |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here dateTime would be a Unix Timestamp and SessionId is Primary Key

**SessionAttendance**

```
-------------------------------------
| SessionID | StudentID |  Status   |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|     1     |    4456   |  'Late'   |
|     1     |    6678   | 'Present' |
-------------------------------------
```

Here SessionID and StudentID are both Primary Keys

**Reason**

Here you don't need to parse all the lists of attendance and statuses. The queries may get a little bigger, but it will save you alot of parsing code.

Example Query :

```
SELECT SessionID FROM SessionAttendance WHERE StudentID  = (SELECT StudentID FROM Students WHERE FirstName = 'John' AND LastName = 'Doe') AND Status = 'Late';
```

It will get all the sessions in which John Doe was late. Simple, right?

**Other Comments**

1. You cannot store arrays of information in an database column. It
   must be a list that is delimited somehow
2. In your application, I reccomend you always keep the StudentID with
       its FirstName and LastName because it will make queries easier, and
       will keep the names localized (so that you can change it in one
       place and will change everywhere else)

Comment: No problem, If the answer was useful, please upvote. That would be great. Thanks! @D.Boxer